# Типы в Firebird

Tags: firebird, sql

Чем отличается VARCHAR от CHAR в Firebird и правильно ли я понял, что типа STRING в Firebird нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, типа **String** в FireBird нет, используется **Char** и **varChar**.

По типам данных почитайте [типы данных](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=tipy_dannyx).